# operator<< in derived classes c++

Tags: c++, derived-class

i have a question for the operatorr `<<` in derived clases ex:

if i have

```
class Base
{
      //......
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,Base &B)
      {
          return  out<<B.x<<B.y<</*........*/<<endl;
      }
      //......    
};
```

is the folowing posible?

```
class Derived: public Base
{
       //......
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,Derived &DERIVEDOBJECT)
       {
           return  out<<DERIVEDOBJECT<<DERIVEDOBJECT.nonderivedvar1 <</*.....*/<< endl;
       }
}
```

or putting the `DERIVEDOBJECT` in the `<<` operator won't result in the `<<` recoqnizing it as a reference just to the base class?

Comment: @Aleksander - Use 4 spaces before each code statement or just use `{}` that is present on the editior window for code formatting.

Answer (score 10):

What you normally want is something like this:

```
class Base { 

     virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) { 
         // write *this to stream
         return os;
     }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Base const &b) { 
     return b.write(os); 
}
```

Then a derived class overrides `write` when/if necessary.

Comment: +1: In the end it is probably best to have a specific write function.

Comment: I think the `b.write` won't call the virtual function because its not a call by pointer.

Comment: @Giovanni: Polymorphism in C++ works just as well with references as it does with pointers.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't see the reference (I usually write `const Base& b` not `Base const &b`).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to cause a recursive call:

```
out<<DERIVEDOBJECT
```

I would do:

```
   friend ostream& operator(ostream& out,Derived &DERIVEDOBJECT)
   {
       return  out << static_cast<Base&>(DERIVEDOBJECT)
                   << DERIVEDOBJECT.nonderivedvar1
                   <<.....<< endl;
   }
```

PS. Space and lowercase letters are your friends.
By convention identifiers that are all uppercase are macros so you may confuse people by using all uppercase identifiers for normal variables.

Comment: +1 for talking about lowercasing variables. THOSE HURTS MY EYES :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result by *upcasting* to the base type:

```
struct base {};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, base const & b ) {
   return o << "base";
};
struct derived : base {};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, derived const & d ) {
   return o << static_cast<base&>(d) << " derived";
}
int main() {
   derived d;
   std::cout << d << std::endl; // "base derived"
}
```